# Can the warlock use his familiar as the point of origin for telepathy?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

One of my players plays as a Warlock with the Great Old One patron and the Pact of the Chain boon.

My question is: can he use telepathy while controlling his familiar (i.e. seeing with its eyes), on a target that is in the range of the familiar but not in the range of the Warlock? 
Thank you.

Comment: Please answer in answers not comments.

Comment: Related [Does Voice of the Chain Master let me cast a purely verbal spell through my familiar?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64608/does-voice-of-the-chain-master-let-me-cast-a-purely-verbal-spell-through-my-fami/64610)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No, a Warlock is not able to use their telepathy through their Familiar.

The section referencing sharing sight/hearing only pertains to sharing those senses. The Warlock is not possessing or otherwise present where the Familiar is, whereas the *Awakened Mind* class feature references (emphasis mine):

> You can communicate telepathically with any creature you 
>   can see within 30 feet **of you**.

Since the Warlock is not actually present where their familiar is, any targets the familiar (and therefore a sense-sharing Warlock) can see are not valid targets.

Answer (score 5):

## No.

PHB page 110, the wording is limited to within 30 feet of you.

> You  can communicate telepathically with any creature you can see within 30 feet of you.